# OAuth2 for Apps Script: Google Apps Script callback is changed dynamically after login

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am using [OAuth2 for Apps Script](https://github.com/gsuitedevs/apps-script-oauth2) to create and authorize OAuth2 tokens as well as refresh them when they expire. As per their documentation, I am using ***Redirect URI*** of below format:

```
https://script.google.com/macros/d/{SCRIPT ID}/usercallback
```

It works for most of the case but it fails for only one user and found that the ***Redirect URI*** is changed for him after login. For a better explanation, I have renamed the domain name to **abc.com**

```
https://script.google.com/macros/abc.com/d/{SCRIPT ID}/usercallback
```

I don't understand how it inserts **abc.com** in the callback. As a result, I am encountering below error:

> Library with identifier OAuth2 is missing (perhaps it was deleted, or you don't have read access?)

Any help or suggestion would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: Copy paste the oauth script directly instead of using the library and see what new error you get

Comment: @TheMaster, your suggestion worked and the error went away. Thanks for your help. But can you please tell me what could be the issue?

Comment: Don't know`````````````````​````````````````` :)

Comment: I've compiled a list of causes and closed this as duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when the authorizing user is logged into a GSuite account associated with the `abc.com` domain. The web app URL changes but other than that, the functionality is not affected.

Comment: but it breaks OAuth2 operation and gives me the error "Library with identifier OAuth2 is missing (perhaps it was deleted, or you don't have read access?)"

Comment: You have to share the Library with "anyone can access" so users outside your domain can access the library.

Comment: Can you please guide me on how to do it?

Comment: Open the library inside Google Script Editor and choose File > Share > Anyone can read.